# Allocator in create publisher ROS2

Tags: c++, ros, ros2

Based on [ROS2 documentation](https://docs.ros2.org/beta3/api/rclcpp/classrclcpp_1_1node_1_1Node.html#a7a098357407370a57b7910f1b51af1cf) there is a third argument called an allocator that can be used when creatinga  publisher. How can this allocator be used ? Does it allocate memory for the publisher ?

```
std::shared_ptr< PublisherT > rclcpp::node::Node::create_publisher  (   const std::string &     topic_name,
const rmw_qos_profile_t &   qos_profile = rmw_qos_profile_default,
std::shared_ptr< Alloc >    allocator = nullptr 
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom allocator will be used for all heap allocations within the context of the publisher. This is the same as how you would use a custom allocator with an `std::vector` as seen [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator). For ROS2, take the following example of a custom allocator.

```
template<typename T>
struct pointer_traits {
  using reference = T &;
  using const_reference = const T &;
};

// Avoid declaring a reference to void with an empty specialization
template<>
struct pointer_traits<void> {
};

template<typename T = void>
struct MyAllocator : public pointer_traits<T> {
public:
  using value_type = T;
  using size_type = std::size_t;
  using pointer = T *;
  using const_pointer = const T *;
  using difference_type = typename std::pointer_traits<pointer>::difference_type;

  MyAllocator() noexcept;

  ~MyAllocator() noexcept;

  template<typename U>
  MyAllocator(const MyAllocator<U> &) noexcept;

  T * allocate(size_t size, const void * = 0);

  void deallocate(T * ptr, size_t size);

  template<typename U>
  struct rebind {
    typedef MyAllocator<U> other;
  };
};

template<typename T, typename U>
constexpr bool operator==(const MyAllocator<T> &,
  const MyAllocator<U> &) noexcept;

template<typename T, typename U>
constexpr bool operator!=(const MyAllocator<T> &,
  const MyAllocator<U> &) noexcept;
```

Then, your main setup would look essentially the same as it would without a custom allocator.

```
auto alloc = std::make_shared<MyAllocator<void>>();
auto publisher = node->create_publisher<std_msgs::msg::UInt32>("allocator_example", 10, alloc);
auto msg_mem_strat =
  std::make_shared<rclcpp::message_memory_strategy::MessageMemoryStrategy<std_msgs::msg::UInt32,
  MyAllocator<>>>(alloc);
std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::memory_strategy::MemoryStrategy> memory_strategy =
std::make_shared<AllocatorMemoryStrategy<MyAllocator<>>>(alloc);
```

For a more complete example I would suggest looking at the TLSF allocator which is designed to be useful for hard real time systems. It can be found [here](https://github.com/ros2/realtime_support/tree/dashing/tlsf_cpp) and a full example can be found [here](https://github.com/ros2/realtime_support/blob/dashing/tlsf_cpp/example/allocator_example.cpp)